# share file among different ipod/iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone

I have an app in which some data file will be created.
The app has iphone/ipad version both.

some customers hope I can add the sharing function for them to exchange/share file.

I think maybe I can use FACEBOOK api to ask the users logged on their facebook account and exchange their current ip address, then do p2p file transfer.

I am not  sure if it is the best way for this requirement and

if sure, is there any p2p sdk for objective-c to do this?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to share those files and keep them synced is the [DropBox API](http://www.dropbox.com/developers)